# How can i skip a section of code lua?

Tags: lua

It is my first lua project and i have a trouble with skipping part of my code. I want the code to stop after part "Cool". So if i write good and it answers cool i want the rest of the code to stop since after that the next question is not relative anymore.

How it works:
Code says: Hello
You say: anything
Code says: How are you?
You say: good
after you say good it will say cool.
If you say anything other than good it will ask "Why?"
e.g. you say: bad
Code says: It will be alright
I want it to stop after "cool" and skip out the further part of the code.

```
os.execute(" cls ")
print("Hello")
    odp = io.read()
        if odp == string then
        end
        tof = true or false

print("How are you?")
    odp2 = io.read()
        if odp2 == "good" then print("Cool") tof = true
            else print("Why?") tof = false
            if tof == true then os.execute(" pause ")   
        end
            end

    odp3 = io.read()
        if odp3 ~= math then print("It will be alright")
            print("Okay, I have to go see you.")
        end
os.execute(" pause ")
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if odp == string then` instead be `if type(odp) == 'string' then`?

Answer (score 2):

When you compile code, it becomes the body of a function. The prototypical way of exiting a function is with a `return` statement. A function can have zero or more `return` statements.

But, since you want to exit the program, you can instead call `os.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You've just got to nest your "if" statements differently. All you need to do is put the rest of the code into the "else" part of your "if" statement, like this:

```
os.execute(" cls ")
print("Hello")
odp = io.read()
if odp == string then
end
tof = true or false

print("How are you?")
odp2 = io.read()
if odp2 == "good" then
    print("Cool")
    tof = true
else
    print("Why?")
    tof = false
    if tof == true then
        os.execute(" pause ")   
    end
-- You had an "end" here.

    odp3 = io.read()
    if odp3 ~= math then
        print("It will be alright")
        print("Okay, I have to go see you.")
    end
    os.execute(" pause ")
end -- You literally just need to move it here.
```

That way, it only gets input from the user after it asks for it, and only if the user doesn't answer, "good" to the "How are you?" question.

Note that I re-indented the code, but it's still the same code in the same order. I just made it more standard-looking and easier to visually see the structure of the program.